# Strange output when looping through text with DBMS_OUTPUT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am writing some code to take an input string and output it in multiple lines to meet a specific line length, I also need it to always start new lines with fresh word so words don't overlap between lines making it difficult to read.

It's probably not the best way to do it but this is what I have come up with;

```
DECLARE
P_output_record          VARCHAR2(1000) := 'Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you dont tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist I really believe he is Antichrist';
v_message_length         INTEGER;
v_written_chars          INTEGER;
v_new_line               VARCHAR2(30);
v_chars_to_write         INTEGER;
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable();
v_message_length := LENGTH(P_output_record);
v_written_chars := 0;

   WHILE(v_written_chars < v_message_length)
   LOOP
      IF(v_written_chars + 28 > v_message_length) THEN
        v_chars_to_write := (v_message_length - v_written_chars);
        v_new_line := SUBSTR( P_output_record, v_written_chars, v_chars_to_write);
      ELSE
        v_new_line := SUBSTR( P_output_record,v_written_chars, 28);
        --get the index of the last space so words dont spill to new lines
        v_chars_to_write := INSTR(v_new_line,' ', -1);
      END IF;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SUBSTR( P_output_record, v_written_chars, v_chars_to_write-1));
      v_written_chars := v_written_chars + v_chars_to_write; 
   END LOOP;
END;
```

This works as each line starts with a new word and words don't spill over lines. However the output is a bit strange, the second line now matter where the space is, or what the complete text is always starts with a space, I have tried merging the words together but it just starts from the space beforehand (but hey that was expected) and even tried different text all together but still get the same result of the second line starting with a space, which suggests there is something wrong with my logic, but I would assume if it is my logic then it would happen on other lines too which it doesn't.

See here how there is a space before on the second line.

```
Well, Prince, so Genoa and
 Lucca are now just family
estates of the Buonapartes.
But I warn you, if you dont
tell me that this means
war, if you still try to
defend the infamies and
horrors perpetrated by that
Antichrist I really believe
he is Antichri
```

P.S I know I'm missing some characters on the end of the last line but that's an issue for another time.

Comment: I always struggle with titles, if anyone can think of a better one please share

Comment: Hmmm, it's bit odd. I remember in the old days DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE used to suppress leading spaces, which was a problem when we wanted them for formatting multi-line output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the fact that you use `v_written_chars` to compute the number of characters already written and to make the substring of the remaining part.

In the first iteration `v_written_chars = 0`, `v_chars_to_write = 27`, so when you do

```
v_written_chars := v_written_chars + v_chars_to_write;
```

you get `v_written_chars = 27`.

At the second iteration, you make the substring starting from the 27th character, which is a blank space, thus getting the string with a leading blank.

An easy way to edit your code could be by initializing

```
v_written_chars = 1;
```

With this edit, the result is:

```
Well, Prince, so Genoa and
Lucca are now just family
estates of the Buonapartes.
But I warn you, if you dont
tell me that this means
war, if you still try to
defend the infamies and
horrors perpetrated by that
Antichrist I really believe
he is Antichri
```

About the last part of the string, once you are on the last row, you don't need to compute the number of characters to write, but you can simply do:

```
v_new_line := SUBSTR( P_output_record, v_written_chars);
```

With the edits, your code becomes:

```
...
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable();
v_message_length := LENGTH(P_output_record);
v_written_chars := 1;

   WHILE(v_written_chars < v_message_length)
   LOOP
      IF(v_written_chars + 28 > v_message_length) THEN
        v_new_line := SUBSTR( P_output_record, v_written_chars);
      ELSE
        v_new_line := SUBSTR( P_output_record,v_written_chars, 28);
        --get the index of the last space so words dont spill to new lines
        v_chars_to_write := INSTR(v_new_line,' ', -1);
      END IF;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SUBSTR( P_output_record, v_written_chars, v_chars_to_write-1));
      v_written_chars := v_written_chars + v_chars_to_write; 
   END LOOP;
END;
```

and the result is:

```
Well, Prince, so Genoa and
Lucca are now just family
estates of the Buonapartes.
But I warn you, if you dont
tell me that this means
war, if you still try to
defend the infamies and
horrors perpetrated by that
Antichrist I really believe
he is Antichrist
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I do find it strange that it was only the second line though

Answer (score 0):

Add `TRIM`, here:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( trim(SUBSTR( P_output_record, v_written_chars, v_chars_to_write-1)));
```

Comment: Adding trim doesn't remove the problem, it just masks it, knowing why it is happening would be ideal to know

Answer (score 0):

Trim will work in your case :

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
P_output_record          VARCHAR2(1000) := 'Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you dont tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist I really believe he is Antichrist';
v_message_length         INTEGER;
v_written_chars          INTEGER;
v_new_line               VARCHAR2(30);
v_chars_to_write         INTEGER;
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable();
v_message_length := LENGTH(P_output_record);
v_written_chars := 0;

   WHILE(v_written_chars < v_message_length)
   LOOP
      IF(v_written_chars + 28 > v_message_length) THEN
        v_chars_to_write := (v_message_length - v_written_chars);
        v_new_line := SUBSTR( P_output_record, v_written_chars, v_chars_to_write);
      ELSE
        v_new_line := SUBSTR( P_output_record,v_written_chars, 28);
        --get the index of the last space so words dont spill to new lines
        v_chars_to_write := INSTR(v_new_line,' ', -1);
      END IF;
      --See this line****************Edited line*************
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( trim(SUBSTR( P_output_record, v_written_chars, v_chars_to_write-1)));
      v_written_chars := v_written_chars + v_chars_to_write; 
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding trim doesn't remove the problem, it just masks it, knowing why it is happening would be ideal to know

Answer (score 0):

Threw this together just for fun, you can also do the following (which uses 80 char max per line, but change to whatever you want).  It also compresses multiple spaces to a single space:

```
select listagg(val, ' ') within group (order by levl)
from (
    with t as (
      select 'Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you dont tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist I really believe he is Antichrist' as str
      from dual )
    select levl, val, trunc(running_count/80)+1 as line
    from (
        select level as levl, regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]+',1,level) as val, sum(length(regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]+',1,level))) over (order by level) as running_count
        from t
        connect by regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]+',1,level) is not null
    )
)
group by line;
```

Output:

> Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the
>   Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you dont tell me that this means war,
>   if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by
>   that Antichrist I really believe he is Antichrist